# Enqueue/ Dequeue OR offer/ poll

Tags: java, queue

This seems like a very basic question, but I've been stuck for hours.

When do we use methods enqueue/ dequeue & when do we use offer/ poll?!

I want to create a PQ of integers with the `void enqueue(int x, int p)` and `int dequeue()` methods, how do I declare such a queue?

Thanks.

Comment: Which queue are you talking about? The standard [`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) doesn't have any `enqueue`/`dequeue` method.

Comment: See [`Queue<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for details on clarifying your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that "PQ" means "priority queue". I've never used such a queue (my mental image of a queue is that of a strictly FIFO structure), but after reading documentation, I think you can do this:

First, you need to create the class of the object you want to store in the queue. Assuming `int` contents and `int` priority:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    private int x, p;

    /*
     * x: Contents
     * p: Priority
     */
    public MyClass(int x, int p) {
        this.x = x;
        this.p = p;
    }

    @override
    public int compareTo(MyClass o) {
        return this.p - o.p;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Now, create your priority queue. If I understood correctly the class documentation, it will use the `compareTo`  method to sort your objects:

```
....
PriorityQueue<MyClass> pq = new PriorityQueue<MyClass>();
....
pq.add(new MyClass(x, p));
....
```

Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Java queues don't have `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods; these operations are done using the following methods:

- Enqueuing:

  - `add(e)`: throws exception if it fails to insert the object
  - `offer(e)`: returns `false` if it fails to insert the object
- Dequeuing:

  - `remove()`: throws exception if the queue is empty
  - `poll()`: returns `null` if the queue is empty
- Take a look to the first object in the queue:

  - `element()`: throws exception if the queue is empty
  - `peek()`: returns `null` if the queue is empty

And now, finally: when to use `offer` and `add`?

About `offer` and `add`: Well, that depends on how do you want to handle the failure of the insertion in the queue:

> The *add* method, which *Queue* inherits from *Collection*, inserts an element unless it would violate the queue's capacity restrictions, in which case it throws *IllegalStateException*. The *offer* method, which is intended **solely for use on bounded queues**, differs from *add* only in that it indicates failure to insert an element by returning *false*.

(see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html)

Hope this helps you

Comment: I'm still not allowed to vote because my reputation is less than 15 :(
I wish I could.

Comment: @InspiringProgramming Happy to help. Just one question: are you using bounded queues? if you are not using them, then you won't be able (or need) to use *offer*  ;-)